# Timeout fatal error handling

Tags: php, error-handling, timeout

I need to send 500 emails and every email I wish to assign a time limit.

Currently, I run an Ajax call to send the email. I need to have an answer to the client Javascript for each email and so fill a progressbar for the user to see the progress of shipments.

The problem is that I used `set_time_limit` and it returns a fatal error. What I want is to manage the timeout (through exceptions or some other idea) to return JSON to be consumed through jQuery.

Comment: Next time, please do not bold all your texts in your question. A simple and short question would sufficient to be readable. Welcome to SO.

Comment: wouldn't hurt to see some of the code...

Answer (score 0):

You can handle fatal errors by register_shutdown_function()

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
function shutdown() {
    $error = error_get_last();
    if ($error['type'] === E_ERROR) {
        //handle timeout error here
    }
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

set_time_limit(1);
// send mails
```